# Setting up phonegap development environment

Tags: html, cordova

I am working on the windows-8 PC. And i have some HTML app gui which i want to convert to android mobile app.
I am new to phonegap.

How to setup the development environment for phonegap?

1> Following tool android developers app tells to use phonegap cli to create new project :--
   http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/04/23/phonegap-developer-app/

This video uses Android sdk to create new project :--
   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF6dzbTDwdY

Which is the best methord to start working with phonegap ?

Do we need android SDK if we work with phonegap cli ?

2> This link tells to use commandline or IDE methord to create phonegap projects :--
   https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki

3> What exactly is the relation between android SDK & phonegap cli .. ?

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend you to use Cordova. Why? Yes, there is no realy reason why to do this, It's rather a question of what you like to work with.

I'm using Cordova. Maybe you read the [Getting started guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) and then the following documentation.

After you installed all, you can open up the CMD and create a new cordova project. If you want to know, how to do this, go on with the posted link above. A little bit under the setup instructions you can find a Guide which explains you, how to setup a new project and so on.

If you work with Cordova, you need Eclipse and i would recommend you to install Genymotion for having more options of deploying an app to a device.

Later on, if you would like to convert an Application to another platform you can use the Phonegap Build from Adobe. But normaly you can use your code like you wrote it for android 1:1 for iOS. Maybe there are some tiny differences, but they would'nt be fixed by the phonegap build i think. So... i would say there is no way to say "You should work with Phonegap" or "You should work with Cordova" it's your choice.

Comment: thanks for reply ... I will go for the phonegap build because with this i can convert my html app to other platform also ... please suggest some good getting start guide (as google is full of many) which you may have used for phonegapCLI... ?

Comment: this link seems good to setup phonegapcli ... http://www.devx.com/wireless/setting-up-phonegap-on-windows-and-osx-using-the-command-line.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build app for android locally you'll need android SDK. This is because phonegap/cordova uses the android SDK to wrap the app.

Basically phonegap/cordova uses the SDK to compile the project for android platform and to build the APK file which can be installed in devices. You can interpret as  Phonegap/cordova cli is an interface between android technology and cross platform technology. Similarly iOS will need some native technology to work with phonegap. Thiese SDK helps to build and package the app for their own platform which you've written in HTML/CSS/Javascript.